# How to prevent css animation for unsupportive browsers and allow for supported if js is deactivated

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-animations

I have handled things so far with a modernizer check. I have an image with a 30% in height bottom box. On :hover a hidden before element gets spanned 100% over the image.

```
.fp-bb {
    .cssanimationsjs &:hover {
        @include animation('box-up 1s');
        height:100%;
        overflow:hidden;
    }   
    .cssanimationsjs &:hover .fp-pro-excerpt {
        display:block;
    }   
    .fp-pro-excerpt {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

That spanning animation is based on:

```
@mixin keyframes($animation-name) {
    @-webkit-keyframes $animation-name {
        @content;
    }
    @-moz-keyframes $animation-name {
        @content;
    }
    @-ms-keyframes $animation-name {
        @content;
    }
    @-o-keyframes $animation-name {
        @content;
    }
    @keyframes $animation-name {
        @content;
    }
}

@mixin animation($str) {
    -webkit-animation: #{$str};
    -moz-animation: #{$str};
    -ms-animation: #{$str};
    -o-animation: #{$str};
    animation: #{$str};
}
```

Basically all the hassle is done for ie9 since it doesn't support css3 animations. So far it works if js is switched on. On all supported browsers the animation is run on the unsupported ie9 nothing happens - perfect. My only problem is would it be possible somehow to cover the case if js is switched off? That the animation runs on supported browsers (at the moment it doesn't) and on the unsupported ie9 no animation runs ( like it does right now). Means would there a way to make modernizer in that case obsolete or is there a way to manage to cover the no-js case too with it? Best regards Ralf

Comment: Does your site fully support running without JavaScript enabled anyway? If it doesn't it doesn't really seem worth the effort. In that case I'd have a separate <noscript> warning saying JS needs to be enabled, which would supersede any browser compatibility checks.

Comment: Yes the rest runs flawless without JS. Basically i was just hoping there would be a way to run the css animation on all supported browsers no matter if js is on or off and ignore the css animation on unsupported browsers like ie9 no matter if js is on or off.

Comment: Consider using a "library" for this purpose, it shall be the easier and cleaner way. GSAP for instance is clever and efficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the css animations to always run when they are available, don't use it as a selector. Just key off of the missing value in javascript (ie `if (no-cssanimationjs) {//do js stuff}`, and ignore the `.cssanimationsjs` completely in your selectors